# How to add file exception in mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to except my execute.php from the rewrite down below, the code isn't mine and I don't know any apache, how can I do this?

```
# BASE REWRITE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?data=$1 [QSA,L]
    # (Line to ignore execute.php)
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a specific exception rule it is easier to add a condition to your existing rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/execute\.php$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ index.php?data=$1 [QSA,END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked flawlessly!
Sidequesion, would it be possible to separate it so I can do a `?data=$1` on that one too?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by "so I can do a ?data=$1 on that one too"...